# Why is this CustomValidator client function not firing?

Tags: asp.net, customvalidator

I have a dropdown with the Id of "BACKGROUND" and if nothing is selected or the value is other, it should fire my client side validation function, but it is not.  Am I missing something?

I have the following client side function:

```
function cv26(oSrc, args) {//BACKGROUND,BG_OTHER 
            alert("cv26"); 
            var otherCtrl = document.getElementById("BG_OTHER"); 
            args.IsValid = (args.Value != " ") || (otherCtrl.value.length > 0); 
        }
```

My Custom validator looks like this:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cv26" runat="server" ErrorMessage="26. Background is required." ControlToValidate="BACKGROUND"  ClientValidationFunction="cv26" Display="Dynamic" ValidateEmptyText="true">*</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Comment: Is the `BG_OTHER` element in a databound control, such as a GridView or ListView? Perhaps the line `document.getElementById("BG_OTHER");` is returning `null` because it can't find it.

Comment: @MarioJVargas - I will point out that it is not even firing the alert, so it is not even getting to that point.

Comment: your validation function name is different... the name in js is cv26 and the one on your customValidator is val_cv26

Comment: @KarthikGanesan - Sorry my mistake, I will fix it.

Comment: is it working now?? It does for me.

Comment: @lucidgold - I am testing. How did you test it so fast.

Comment: @lucidgold - It is still not working.

Comment: First things first:

I dont't see the `runat="server"` tag in your question.

Secondly, I also don't see `EnableClientScript="true"` in the tag. Try adding this and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

**Problem #1: Function names DO NOT MATCH**

ClientValidationFunction does not match the function name.

In your javascript you declare function cv26, but in your CustomValidator you have val_cv26 for ClientValidationFunction. So you either change your javascript function to val_cv26 or change the ClientValidationFunction to cv26

**Problem #2: Validation Groups**

In your original code you did not specify any validation groups.  Notice that both the *CustomValidator* and *Button2* have **ValidationGroup="hi"**. They must belong to the same validation group. You need validation groups if you have multiple buttons for example and you only want one of the buttons to validate user input. If you only have ONE button then this is not a problem.

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="BACKGROUND" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text=" --- SELECT ---" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="A"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="B"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="C"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:CustomValidator ID="cv26" runat="server" 
                     ErrorMessage="26. Background is required." 
                     ControlToValidate="BACKGROUND"  
                     ClientValidationFunction="cv26" 
                     Display="Dynamic" ValidateEmptyText="true"   
                     ValidationGroup="hi">*</asp:CustomValidator>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
            Text="Submit" onclick="Button1_Click"  
            ValidationGroup="hi" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function cv26(oSrc, args) {
    args.IsValid = (args.Value != ""); 
}
```

- **When is your validation expected to fire?**
- **Please provide the declaration for BACKGROUND**
- **Please provide the declaration for BG_Other**
- **Are BACKGROUND and BG_OTHER on the same ASPX page?**

Comment: I have updated my answer. This is the example that is working for me.

Comment: I am adding the validation groups. None of the controls had that, is it required?

Comment: Does it work now? If not, please update your code on the post.

Comment: Nope, the javascript is in sync. I added validation groups and it still did not work

Comment: Please provide more code. You need to show Submit button if you are using one, you need to show what BACKGROUND control looks like, and you need to show BG_Other as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the value in ClientValidationFunction. It should be `ClientValidationFunction="cv26"` as it cannot find `val_cv26`

Change this:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cv26" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="26. 
    Background is required." 
    ControlToValidate="BACKGROUND"  
    ClientValidationFunction="val_cv26" 
    Display="Dynamic" 
    ValidateEmptyText="true">*</asp:CustomValidator>
```

To:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cv26" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="26. 
    Background is required." 
    ControlToValidate="BACKGROUND"  
    ClientValidationFunction="cv26" 
    Display="Dynamic" 
    ValidateEmptyText="true">*</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Or rename your JavaScript function to `val_cv26`.

Comment: Is the `BG_OTHER` element in a databound control, such as a GridView or ListView? Are you seeing any JavaScript errors? (In your Web browser, assuming Chrome or FireBug in Firefox, open the developer console by hitting F12.) The former question is very important to know about as it could be a hint that your JavaScript isn't finding the element.